# How to delete the selected columns in table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Here my requirement is selecting columns that has to be displayed and other need to be hidden. So I am getting the unselected column IDs in an array and looping through that array to hide things, but its not working properly. Please find me a better solution.

```
for(var z=0;z<col_compared.length-1;z++)
{               
    $('#My_online_Rep_Table thead tr').find('th:eq('+col_compared[z]+')').hide();
    $('#My_online_Rep_Table tbody tr').find('td:eq('+col_compared[z]+')').hide();
}
```

`col_compared[]` is an array of column IDs that needs to be hidden.

Comment: `"selecting columns"` how?? plz share this too.

Comment: can you share the markup for the table and sample for the values in col_compared

Comment: <table id="My_online_Rep_Table">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th width="210" id="1">col 1</th>
                        <th id="2">col 2</th>
                        <th id="3">col 3</th>
                        <th id="4">col 4</th>
                        <th id="5">col 5</th>
                        <th id="6">col 6</th>
                        <th id="7">col 7</th>
                        <th id="8">col 8</th>
                        <th id="9">col 9</th>
                    
                    </tr>
                </thead></table>

Answer (score 1):

If your `for` is wrong, if there is only one item then the loop will not get executed otherwise the last item will not get executed

The array index starts from 0 to length - 1, since you are checking `z < col_compared.length - 1` you are leaving the last item in the array out.

```
var $body = $('#My_online_Rep_Table tbody tr'),
    $header = $('#My_online_Rep_Table thead tr');
for (var z = 0; z < col_compared.length; z++) {
    $header.find('th:eq(' + col_compared[z] + ')').hide();
    $body.find('td:eq(' + col_compared[z] + ')').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want delete a particalar element or div any dom element you can use this method

```
$("#div1").destroy();
```

this is delete element with id= div1

for your case u can use this in your for loop;

```
$('#My_online_Rep_Table thead tr').find('th:eq('+col_compared[z]+')').destroy()
```

Comment: `.destroy()` where is it in jquery specified?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
            for(var z=0;z<col_compared.length-1;z++)
            {               
                $('#My_online_Rep_Table thead tr th').eq(col_compared[z]).hide();
                $('#My_online_Rep_Table tbody tr td').eq(col_compared[z]).hide();
            }
```